# chrome extension navigation within an extension using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a simple chrome extension which will have a list and an add button.

on clicking 'add button' the user is taken to a new html page within the extension with a form.

i have a Back button on the form page which needs to take the user back to the list page.

how do i navigate from page 2 of the extension to page 1 of the extension?

**EDIT**

the history object in the extension is of the browser and not of the extension. 
i need to go back within the extension

**EDIT**

Sample images to show the two pages of the extension
[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.write('<a href="popup.html"><button class="button">Back to home</button></a>')
```

When the extension is open, the page refreshes back to the original `popup.html` file.

If you want standard HTML rather than through javascript... try

```
<a href="popup.html"><button class="button">Back to home</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the user comes from, and you need navigate back and reload the previous page completely, then you should change the location, without using `history`. Otherwise, if you want to simulate the "go back" function of the browser you can use `history.go(-1)`.

By the way, you cannot use inline code inside an extension (see [this CSP page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)), so you'll have to create a script and load it in your page, here's an example:

HTML:

```
<input id="go_back" type="button" value="Back"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

File `script.js`:

```
document.getElementById('go_back').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    history.go(-1);

    // or:
    window.location.href = "<old-url>";
});
```

Comment: thanks, i tried the js u wrote, but weirdly history.go(-1); did not work!! chrome extension page did not go back

Comment: i just realised the history object is of the browser and not the extension. i need to go back within the extension

Comment: @Anand can you tell me exactly which is the page with the "back" button and which is the page you want to go back to?

Comment: its all within the extension popup. I have added two images of the extension for the two pages. I want to go back from page 2 to page 1